# self.navigationController?.pushViewController Not Working with Xcode 11.1

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I recently started a new project with the newest Xcode and now the function
`self.navigationController?.pushViewController` to push a new controller is not working.

I've looked at similar answers and checked my own old  projects where it is working, they mentioned the Navigation controller being `nil` but I thought I addressed that.

I think it has to do with the new `SceneDelegate` file that is part of how views are managed.

Here is the code of the regarding the first `VC` that pops up in the app in the `SceneDelegate` file.

```
 let nav1 = UINavigationController()
        let mainView = MainViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) //ViewController = Name of your controller
        nav1.viewControllers = [mainView]
        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
//            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            window.rootViewController = nav1
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

Comment: Same issue and I am still trying to fix it. So annoying

Comment: I am able to delete storyboards but for some reason can't get rid of the reference. Keeps throwing an error. I guess that had to do with the scene delegate as well

Answer (score 2):

Remove SceneDelegate.swift file and it's delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Xcode 11.1 with new project.

Remove **SceneDelegate.swift** file and also remove its delegate methods from **AppDelegate.swift**. This solution worked for me.

My open source code created with Xcode 11 and Swift 5.
https://github.com/gauravparvadiya/swift-news-reddit

Answer (score 0):

Like they said above,
remove SceneDelegate.swift,
the sceneDelegate methods from the AppDelegate.swift
PLUS
remove these from the plist file:
UISceneConfigurations
UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication

```
                key: UISceneConfigurationName
                value: Default Configuration
                key: UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                value: $(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate
                key: UISceneStoryboardFile
                value: Main
```

If you fail to remove these, you will get a black view when you run your app. But, the error messages in the console should help guide you to delete the necessary items from the plist.